# JQuery function stops fetching data when trying to submit large amount of parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion-9

Run Coldfusion 9 on Windows 2008 R2 Server.

I have a cfm page with multiple dropdowns (some are cfselect) and dynamically generated lists of checkboxes interdependent on each other. I am using JQuery to submit data to cfc functions and to display data.

It was all working fine until we added new company with large number of records. This translated into large URL query string with a lot of parameters submitted for processing. That's when we started to have problems. I noticed when trying to directly submitting URL, if the total number of characters in URL is more than 2114 I get an error status code 302 Redirect and nothing is displayed.

I tried to play with postParametersLimit and postSizeLimit increasing to 1000.0 in neo-runtime.xml and restarting server but, this did not help.

Below is jquery function:

```
function populateBills(){
var plID;

if ($('#planenrolldate_id').val() == undefined)
  plID = $('input[name=planenrolldate_id]').val();
else
  plID = $('#planenrolldate_id').val();

var sID = $('#sponsor_id').val(); 
var pID = $('#plan_id').val();

var fromMonth = $('#from_month').val();
var fromYear = $('#from_year').val();
var toMonth = $('#to_month').val();
var toYear = $('#to_year').val();

$.ajax({
  type:"POST",
 url:"../components/billing/custompremstatus.cfc?method=GetBillsArr&planenrolldate_id=" + plID + "&sponsorid=" + sID + "&fM=" + fromMonth + "&fY=" + fromYear + "&tM=" + toMonth + "&tY=" + toYear,
dataType: "json",          
success: 
 function(data){                  
  $.each(data, function(index, item) {
   addBillsCheckboxes(item.bill_id,item.bill_period);
  });
}, //end the error function
error: 
 function(){
  alert("An error has occurred while fetching bills");
 } //end the error function
}); // end ajax call       
 } // end of function
```

============UPDATE==============

I changed POST style to:

```
url:"../components/billing/custompremstat.cfc",
            data: {
                method: "GetBillsArr",
                sponsor_id: sID,
                planenrolldate_id: plID,
                fM: fromMonth, 
                fY: fromYear, 
                tM: toMonth, 
                tY: toYear
            },
```

As a result I am getting error "The PLANENROLLDATE_ID parameter to the GetBillsArr function is required but was not passed in.  
The error occurred on line -1. "

In the console planenrolldate_id looks like array. How to change parameter?

From console:

```
fM  9
fY  2014
method  GetBillsArr
planenrolldate_id[] 564
planenrolldate_id[] 561
sponsor_id  59
tM  9
tY  2014
```

Comment: why do you need to create a big query string when you are using `post`? You aren't even sending data as part of the post

Comment: I changed to POST style but, now getting an error. I described it in the UPDATE to my post. Thanks

Comment: seems like you need to adjust your CF code to handle array sent

Comment: In the function planenrolldate_id argument is set to "array" data type, I tried "any" data type. Either does not work.

Comment: since you resolved how to get the data to server I suggest you start a new question that shows your CF code as none is shown here

Comment: This does not resolve the problem but, I see your point. Will add new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't POST with a GET-style url.  You aren't really posting like this....

Send the parameters to the script with a POST as data

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "../components/billing/custompremstatus.cfc",
  data: { 
     method : "GetBillsArr",
     planenrolldate_id : plID,
    // ... etc
 }
});
```

and of course look for the posted version of the request in your CFM script.

Answer (score -1):

Try to set the below parameters and than check
php.ini

post_max_size=20M
upload_max_filesize=20M
.htaccess

php_value post_max_size 20M
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
Which one to use depends on what you have access to.